# python pymysql and CURDATE() not expanding properly

Tags: python, mysql

**Has anyone run into this issue where trying to run a query below:**

```
import pymysql
from pprint import pprint

conn = pymysql.connect(.....)

cur = conn.cursor()

build_select = "SELECT CURDATE();"
cur.execute(build_select)
results = cur.fetchall()
pprint(results)
```

**outputs**:

```
((datetime.date(2016, 2, 2),),)
```

**whereas when running the same query in a MySQL console, you get the following output?**

```
mysql> SELECT CURDATE();
+------------+
| CURDATE()  |
+------------+
| 2016-02-02 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That looks pretty reasonable to me.  MySQL and Python have different ways of representing things.  Since it wouldn't be very helpful to a Python programmer for `cur.fetchall()` to return such a string, it instead converts it to a datetime object which is much easier to deal with.

Comment: this is a very stripped down version of the actual report query.. rather its just the portion that i identified to be broken . Ideally i'd like to retain the original query, and allow MySQL to do the CURDATE() expansion, then just return the value as you'd expect in any SELECT statement.